# Probability of winning a multiple-round game, where a player needs to get to $n$ points before losing all their initial point.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, gambling

I'm trying to do the following problem in Sheldon Ross' A First Course In Probability (page 86-87).

> EXAMPLE $4k$.
> Suppose that initially there are $r$ players, with player $i$ having $n_i$ units, $n_i > 0, i = 1,\dots,r$. At each stage, two of the players are chosen to play a game, with the winner of the game receiving $1$ unit from the loser. Any player whose fortune drops to $0$ is
> eliminated, and this continues until a single player has all $n = \sum_{i=1}^r n_i$ units, with that player designated as the victor. Assuming that the results of successive games
> are independent and that each game is equally likely to be won by either of its two
> players, find $P_i$, the probability that player $i$ is the victor.

I've also just solved another problem from Ross' book, the solution of which I thought could help with the one above.

> Independent trials resulting in a success with probability $p$ and a failure with probability $1 − p$ are performed. What is the probability that $n$ successes occur before $m$ failures?

The answer to this problem is
$$P_{n,m} = \sum_{k=n}^{m+n-1} {{m+n-1} \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{m+n-1-k}$$

Now back to example $4k$. I was considering some player $i$. This player can win anything between $0$ and $n-n_i$ units, and lose anything between $0$ and $n_i$ units. Furthermore, the player would win the game if she can get $n-n_i$ wins before losing $n_i$ times. Applying the formula above, with the corresponding $p = 1 - p = \frac{1}{2}$, we would have:
$$P_i = \sum_{k=n-n_i}^{n-1} {{n-1} \choose k} \left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)^k \left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{n-k-1} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=n-n_i}^{n-1} {{n-1} \choose k}$$

However, the correct answer turns out to be $P_i = \frac{n_i}{n}$, which is different from what I got. I'd like to know where I went wrong with the above argument.

Comment: The questions are different: for example, the first game could go on an arbitrarily long time while the second will finish in at most $n+m-1$ rounds.  So there is not reason to suppose the best approach for one will help in answering the other.  Your statement *"the player would win the game if she can get $n−n_i$ wins before losing $n_i$ times"* does not apply as  here the player would win the game if she can get $n−n_i$ **more wins than loses**  before getting to $n_i$ **more losses than wins**.

Comment: One way of answering the new question is to say this is a fair game, and the expected number of units held by a particular player never changes.  The effect is that $p_i n +(1-p_i)0=n_i$ so $p_i=\frac{n_i}{n}$

Comment: I see. I failed to account for the cases where the player just go back and forth between winning some rounds and then losing some rounds, without ever getting to $0$ or $n$ points.

Comment: The problem can be solved by the Gambler's ruin problem with fair coin flipping. See the Ross's book or [link][1] for more details. Note that the game in Gambler's ruin problem can be contniued infintly, while the game in the problem you used stops after a finite number of $m+n-1$ steps. 


  [1]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_ruin